# How to remove search bar from Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I use Firebug for development. However, it kind of seriously interrupts my development workflow because it prevents me from using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to switch the focus to the address bar of Firefox such that I can reload the page after some modification. Instead, it seems as if <kbd>Tab</kbd> will strictly only direct focus to the Firebug search bar. Even repeated hits of <kbd>Tab</kbd> will stay on the firebug search bar.

That's annoying. How can I remove the Firebug search bar?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using Firefox 30.0 + Firebug 2.0 on Windows. Pressing Tab lets me switch to the address bar of Firefox. What configuration do you have?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the search bar from Firebug you would need to change it's code. I don't think you want to do this, but to remove the search bar you have to remove the following code line (in Firebug 2.0) from the `firebugOverlay.xul` file:

```xml
<textbox flex="70" id="fbSearchBox" type="fbSearchBox"/>
```

See this line on GitHub:

https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/7f621b61c3961e3390e1caf60a733e28d3b42336/extension/content/firebug/firebugOverlay.xul#L117

To switch to the Firefox address bar you can also simply press <kbd>F6</kbd>. If you just want to reload the page, you can press <kbd>F5</kbd>. Both keys work fine in combination with Firebug.
Furthermore there's a [list of all shortcuts at the Mozilla website](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly).

Answer (score -1):

Check this one : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-navigation-bar/?src=search

parent link : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/939601